# significance of Partition over in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

**Query:**

```
SELECT department_id "Dept", hire_date "Date", last_name "Name",
   LISTAGG(last_name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date, last_name)
     OVER (PARTITION BY department_id) as "Emp_list"
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date < '01-SEP-2003'
ORDER BY "Dept", "Date", "Name";
```

```
     Dept Date      Name            Emp_list
    ----- --------- --------------- --------------------------------
       30 07-DEC-02 Raphaely        Raphaely; Khoo
       30 18-MAY-03 Khoo            Raphaely; Khoo
       40 07-JUN-02 Mavris          Mavris
       50 01-MAY-03 Kaufling        Kaufling; Ladwig
       50 14-JUL-03 Ladwig          Kaufling; Ladwig
       70 07-JUN-02 Baer            Baer
       90 13-JAN-01 De Haan         De Haan; King
       90 17-JUN-03 King            De Haan; King
      100 16-AUG-02 Faviet          Faviet; Greenberg
      100 17-AUG-02 Greenberg       Faviet; Greenberg
      110 07-JUN-02 Gietz           Gietz; Higgins
      110 07-JUN-02 Higgins         Gietz; Higgins
```

**Doubt:**
What is significance of Partition over here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short answer.  You should read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) on analytic functions, though.

The function `list_agg()` -- as with many Oracle functions -- can be either an aggregation function or an analytic function.  I assume you know what an aggregation function is.  The `group by` clause puts all rows with the same value of the aggregation variables and summarizes them into a single row.

Analytic functions are similar, but different of course.  They also find groups of rows that are similar to each other.  However, they don't summarize them on one row.  They simply add a new column with that information.  The `partition by` clause specifies how the groups are created.

So, this query is combining all the `last_name`s in rows with the same `department_id`.  The `last_names` are ordered by hiring date and then the name.  This list is then attached to every line in the same table.  You can compare your query to a similar aggregation query:

```
SELECT department_id "Dept",
       LISTAGG(last_name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date, last_name)
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date < '01-SEP-2003' 
GROUP BY department_id;
```